# stuck on i2cmaster library

Tags: libraries, c

i want to try repair my batteries with smbus hacker code over arduino.
first it was has some problems. i have tried to fix them and i fix.
now i have problem on library

> i2c\test_i2cmaster.c.o: In function `main':
>   C:\Users\ugur\Documents\Arduino\libraries\i2c/test_i2cmaster.c:22: multiple definition of`main'
>   i2c\main.c.o:C:\Users\ugur\Documents\Arduino\libraries\i2c/main.c:88: first defined here
>   i2c\twimaster.c.o: In function `i2c_init':
>   C:\Users\ugur\Documents\Arduino\libraries\i2c/twimaster.c:31: multiple definition of`i2c_init'
>   i2c\i2cmaster.S.o:(.text+0x10): first defined here
>   i2c\twimaster.c.o: In function `i2c_start':
>   C:\Users\ugur\Documents\Arduino\libraries\i2c/twimaster.c:42: multiple definition of`i2c_start'
>   i2c\i2cmaster.S.o:(.text+0x1a): first defined here
>   i2c\twimaster.c.o: In function `i2c_start_wait':
>   C:\Users\ugur\Documents\Arduino\libraries\i2c/twimaster.c:78: multiple definition of`i2c_start_wait'
>   i2c\i2cmaster.S.o:(.text+0x36): first defined here
>   i2c\twimaster.c.o: In function `i2c_rep_start':
>   C:\Users\ugur\Documents\Arduino\libraries\i2c/twimaster.c:130: multiple definition of`i2c_rep_start'
>   i2c\i2cmaster.S.o:(.text+0x22): first defined here
>   i2c\twimaster.c.o: In function `i2c_stop':
>   C:\Users\ugur\Documents\Arduino\libraries\i2c/twimaster.c:141: multiple definition of`i2c_stop'
>   i2c\i2cmaster.S.o:(.text+0x4a): first defined here
>   i2c\twimaster.c.o: In function `i2c_write':
>   C:\Users\ugur\Documents\Arduino\libraries\i2c/twimaster.c:161: multiple definition of`i2c_write'
>   i2c\i2cmaster.S.o:(.text+0x5a): first defined here
>   i2c\twimaster.c.o: In function `i2c_readAck':
>   C:\Users\ugur\Documents\Arduino\libraries\i2c/twimaster.c:182: multiple definition of`i2c_readAck'
>   i2c\i2cmaster.S.o:(.text+0x96): first defined here
>   i2c\twimaster.c.o: In function `i2c_readNak':
>   C:\Users\ugur\Documents\Arduino\libraries\i2c/twimaster.c:197: multiple definition of`i2c_readNak'
>   i2c\i2cmaster.S.o:(.text+0x92): first defined here

the library is ;

## ifndef  F_CPU

## define F_CPU 16000000UL

## endif

## include

## include

## define F_SCL 100000UL // SCL frequency

## define Prescaler 1

## define TWBR_val ((((F_CPU / F_SCL) / Prescaler) - 16 ) / 2)

void I2C_init(void){
    TWBR = TWBR_val;
}

uint8_t I2C_start(uint8_t address){
    // reset TWI control register
    TWCR = 0;
    // transmit START condition 
    TWCR = (1<

```
// check if the start condition was successfully transmitted
if((TWSR & 0xF8) != TW_START){ return 1; }

// load slave address into data register
TWDR = address;
// start transmission of address
TWCR = (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEN);
// wait for end of transmission
while( !(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)) );

// check if the device has acknowledged the READ / WRITE mode
uint8_t twst = TW_STATUS & 0xF8;
if ( (twst != TW_MT_SLA_ACK) && (twst != TW_MR_SLA_ACK) ) return 1;

return 0;
```

}

void I2C_write(uint8_t data){
    // load data into data register
    TWDR = data;
    // start transmission of data
    TWCR = (1<

```
if( (TWSR & 0xF8) != TW_MT_DATA_ACK ){ return 1; }

return 0;
```

}

uint8_t I2C_read_ack(void){

```
// start TWI module and acknowledge data after reception
TWCR = (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEN) | (1<<TWEA); 
// wait for end of transmission
while( !(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)) );
// return received data from TWDR
return TWDR;
```

}

uint8_t I2C_read_nack(void){

```
// start receiving without acknowledging reception
TWCR = (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEN);
// wait for end of transmission
while( !(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)) );
// return received data from TWDR
return TWDR;
```

}

void I2C_stop(void){
    // transmit STOP condition
    TWCR = (1<

how i can fix it ?
i am new on arduino and c/c++

Comment: The code your trying to compile has multiple errors in it.  This isn't the proper place to find help fixing those errors.  Why don't you download the already compiled binary?

Comment: cant find compiled binary

Comment: Well we cannot help you compile the code.  You didn't even post the entire file, even if we could, help with this particular type of question.

Comment: there is library ; http://www29.zippyshare.com/v/63344687/file.html

Comment: You will have to find a more reputable website then that before I visit it.  **It came up as malicious in my research.**

Comment: Ok,Forget it....I dont have any time to send anybody malicious files... Nobody does this want help... I trying to make something , i have work with this program all day but cant get nothing...Good days...

Answer (score -1):

Anyway to use another i2c library ?
main program is this

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=d7pkki3cs71cv85c0jfrl034k5&action=dlattach;topic=62955.0;attach=3389